# convert c# to vb an event, and cannot be called directly

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert the following c# code to vb.net, but an error raised at the vb converted lines: `Me.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted`.

c#:

```
private void OnZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKOperationCompleted(object arg)
{
    if ((this.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted != null))
    {
        System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
        this.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted(this, new ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
    }
}
```

vb:

```
Private Sub OnZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKOperationCompleted(ByVal arg As Object)
    If (Me.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim invokeArgs As System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs = DirectCast(arg, System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)
        Me.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted(Me, New ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.[Error], invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState))
    End If
End Sub
```

How should I convert the c# line `this.ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted`?

Comment: By the way, there are a lot of online converters what are often very handy, e.g. http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @Rhumborl I tried to convert his code with it, and it's the same result (no RaiseEvent called).

Comment: You have to paste enough code into the converter for the converter to be able to know that 'ZBAPI_MEDDOC_.....' is an event.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`RaiseEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/fwd3bwed.aspx) in VB.NET, which also does not require the `null` check for if there are event listeners attached:

```
Private Sub OnZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKOperationCompleted(ByVal arg As Object)

    Dim invokeArgs As System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs = DirectCast(arg, System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)

    RaiseEvent ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompleted(Me, New ZBAPI_MEDDOC_CREATE_LINKCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.[Error], invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState))

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `invokeArgs.Error` property have to be written with `[]` ?

Comment: @Drarig29 Because `Error` is a [reserved word in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx), so you need to escape it, the same as using [`@` in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), e.g. `public void RunEvent(@event someEvent){}`